# How can find and replace muiti text at once?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text:

> the Swiss Army knife of sound processing tools: it can convert sound
>   files between many different file formats & audio devices, and can
>   apply many sound effects & transformations, as well as doing basic
>   analysis and providing input to more capable analysis and plotting
>   tools.

Example: I want find: `audio,sound` and replace it by `Whitespace` at one time.
Because I have a very large text file so I can't find every word use `Find/Replace and replace` use `Replace all`.

Comment: So you just want to replace the words `audio`and `sound` with whitespace? Then a simple RegExp like `(audio|sound)` will do.

Comment: This question is very unclear.  Perhaps try giving a concrete example or putting quotations around text segments you are parsing through.

Answer (score 0):

more information needed.
But if you are using windows
try Textpad - [text editor](http://www.textpad.com/) which is good with even very large files

Otherwise if you are on linux, have a look at SED [sed search & replace](http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html)

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `audio|sound`
Replace with: `<whatever>`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/original/replace with/g' *
```

'*' is to replace it with list of all text file its a wildcard symbol

or you can use [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or sublime text